# Angular filter by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have  a ng-repeat element

My single element contains some properties

```
{
name: 'full name',
email: 'aaa@bbb.cc',
partner_name: 'partner'
}
```

I want a single search that search in all fields.
The user can type the email or the partner name or the name.

My Code:

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12"> <input type="text" ng-model="search.name"
                 placeholder="Quick Search user"
                 class="form-control" ></div>
</div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="el in contacts | filter:search" class='partner-panel animate-repeat'>
    <div class="alert " ng-class="css" >
        <div class="name">
            (<span ng-bind="el.id"> </span>) <span ng-bind="el.name"></span>
        </div>
        <div ng-bind="el.email">
        </div>
        <div ng-bind="el.partner_name">
        </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) you should use

```
<input ng-model="search.$">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need input for name, mail and partner_name and you can use filter like this:

```
   ng-repeat="el in contacts | filter:{name: search.name, email: search.mail, partner_name: search.partner}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom filter that will apply whatever search logic you need:

```
app.filter('myFilter', function() {
    return function(contacts, search) {
        if (!search) {
            return contacts;
        }

        // search.name will contain the input entered in the field    
        var searchRegex = new RegExp(search.name, 'i');
        return contacts.filter(function(item) {
            // look for match in name or email properties of the contact
            return searchRegex.test(item.name) || searchRegex.test(item.email);
        });
    };
});
```

and then:

```
<div ng-repeat="el in contacts | myFilter:search">
```

This way you could have a single search box which will look into different properties of the contact model:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="search.name"
       placeholder="Quick Search user"
       class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

`ng-repeat="el in contacts | filter1 | filter2 | filter3"`

placing the fields in the three filters as documented in AngularJS documentation  [{{ expression | filter1 | filter2 }}](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)